# How to stream data from snowflake to kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to build a data pipeline from snowflake to Kafka.
Preferably I want to use AWS MSK.
I could find multiple docs for streaming data in to snowflake from Kafka but I am looking for other way around.

Comment: Rajeev can you not write a Python producer that will get the data from snowflake and push to kafka. You can use the confluent-kafka client package to push the data to MSK

Comment: i am also trying to write a code in java to get data from snowflake and publish into Kafka topic with CDC. are you having any solution for this?any documentation or links